# Samsung Xpress M2070FW won't print PDF on Ubuntu 17.10 x64

Tags: drivers, printing, 64-bit, pdf

I tried to install HP or Samsung ULD drivers but still problems printing only pdf.
Scanning is ok, print text files is ok!
I tried to use "Samsung M2070 Series, driverless, cups-filters 1.17.9" or "Samsung M2070 Series [en]" drivers without success.
Please, someone help me please?
Thanks a lot

Comment: when you say "tried to install": do you think you succeeded please? If you open the PRINTERS folder; there should be one? icon for your Samsung; if you right-click on that; look in PROPERTIES; then down to MAKE & MODEL can you tell us what is in that line please?

Comment: the reference to "Samsung M2070 Series, driverless, cups-filters 1.17.9" would be the airprint-compatible driver set up; airprint came with 17.04 and the printer is listed here as compatible https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201311 but 17.10 seems to have printing problems; we can only hope that it is sorted by April; when 18.04 appears

Comment: @pdc: yes, the drivers are installed without issues.
The printer is listed and proprierties are shown but everytime I shut Off and then On using "additional printer settings" -> (right click on printer) Properties it loose "orientation-requested" and "print-quality" values...
Anyway, the printer and the scanner are working, I have issues when I'm printing the PDF's (using the standard evince viewer)

Answer (score 0):

for Samsung's drivers, one would go here https://support.hp.com/nz-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2070-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16450377 and click to download what seems currently to be  uld_v1.00.37_00.99.tar.gz

then open a terminal; copy each command below line by line; PASTE into the terminal; hit the enter key; move to copy the next line ..

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf uld_v1.00.37_00.99.tar.gz
cd uld
sudo ./install.sh
```

and that final script runs the install script; .. and all should be good

Comment: Hi, I unistalled old drivers (suldr via ppa) and installed that like suggested from hp.
I've to check all conditions but now I've 2 printers in control panel, one is named "M2070" and the other is named "Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC30CDA7218B30_".
I tried to remove the printer from the control panel after unistalling drivers but the printer appear everytime...

Comment: The printer initially was connected both usb and wi-fi, now the usb cable has been disconnected.

Comment: as in top comment: look in MAKE & MODEL and tell us what each icon says please;

Comment: that icon says "Samsung M2070 Series"

Comment: does either make the printer work?

Comment: playing with drivers now I've 2 printers. "M2070" and "Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC30CDA7218B30_". I disconnected the usb cable so it's connected just only via wi-fi. I can't remove the second printer, it reappear always. How do I remove the second printer?

Comment: there is often a cups "auto" function where it just keeps adding it back .. you can google how to change it but seems like the old fix doesn't work in more recent releases ..

Comment: hi, I resolved removing the printer just creating a file "/etc/init/cups-browsed.override" with "manual" as the first and only word inside. now the printer named "M2070" works fine.

Comment: that is great; well done; thanks for that; traditionally files in etc/init end in conf: did you need to do that?

Comment: no, simply named "cups-browsed.override".
a lot of files ends in ".conf" but seems ".override" is specific for this use. 
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: since "cups-browsed.override" trick stops working I removed all drivers and printers.
then I tried to install the printer M2070 from zero without drivers but the scan doesn't work and sometime I received messages referring the drivers needs for the applications, so I reinstalled the uld 1.00.37, full printer and scanner.
The scan works perfectly and the printer needs to point to connection "socket://192.168.xxx.yyy" instead the default connection to work correctly.