# 18.04 will not delete printer - keeps returning

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing

Just installed 18.04, my wireless printer appears in **Settings** > **Devices** > **Printers** but doesn't connect/print.

I have therefore downloaded the printer driver from the manufacturer, Pantum,  and installed it, this has created a new printer in the list which works.

Now I want to remove the non working one, I can delete it but then if I return to the page it is back.

I have followed these instructions: [Cannot remove printer cups adds it back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012247/cannot-remove-printer-cups-adds-it-back) with no result. In CUPS I only have one printer (the working one).

Never had these issues with 16.04 and missing Unity already...

Comment: Just to add I have tried everything off of here too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation - the printer still appears.

Comment: Same here, unfortunately. No known solution that used to work before 18.04 works in 18.04, other than setting "enable-dbus=no" in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf. But setting enable-dbus to no causes LibreOffice to become unresponsive when a print dialogue is invoked, so it is not really a working solution.

Comment: Linked https://askubuntu.com/a/1436064/456438

Answer (score 10):

edit

`/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`

Then make change:

`BrowseRemoteProtocols none`

save and then restart CUPS

`service cups restart`

Comment: But what if you have, for example, a laptop which needs to browse remote protocols to print at all? If printers reappear as a consequence of remote browsing, then there must be some remote device which still thinks that the non-working printer still exists.

Comment: Thanks. This worked in ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

Set `CreateRemoteCUPSPrinterQueues` and `CreateIPPPrinterQueues` in `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` to "`No`" and restart `cups-browsed service`.

Answer (score 0):

This way won't work. Instead you should go to the printer internal settings via panel or web GUI and in network settings disable mDNS/Avahi. The printer will stop broadcasting itself to the network and once deleted from your PC it won't come back.