# ubuntu 18.04 - cannot stop browing LAN printers

Tags: 18.04, printing

Ubuntu is keeping browsing the LAN and installing printers automatically.

How to stop that?

1 - I have tried :

```
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed
```

2 - I have tried editing

> /etc/cups/cups-browsedconf

and replacing `BrowseRemoteProtocols dnssd cups` by

```
BrowseRemoteProtocols none
```

But both solution doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

update - list of printers  in both screens, I don't understand why in the screen with only two printers, there isn't all the printers listed in the background screen.
[image]

Comment: Have you deleted all printers from CUPS after stopping the service?  They don't drop off automatically.

Comment: Have you tried the advice contained in this thread? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059774/18-04-will-not-delete-printer-keeps-returning

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work either